# Auth0 how to send email as username

Tags: auth0, auth0-lock

After I upgraded Auth0 from version 9 to version 11, I face a problem while authenticating.

I have a request URL: https://my-domain.auth0.com/co/authenticate, and all the parameters in my request look good, except username. It sends truncated email as username parameter, i.e. if I type 'someone@gmail.com', it only sends 'someone' as username.

```
export class AuthService {
idToken: string;
lock = new Auth0Lock(myConfig.clientID, myConfig.domain, {
      responseType: 'id_token token',
         .........
      params: {
--------------->>>>>>>>>> if I write here:
          username: 'someone@gmail.com',
--------------->>>>>>>>>> then it sends this email as username parameter, 
no matter what I type in the login form. 
IS THERE A WAY TO WRITE SOMETHING LIKE username: 'email' (this one is not working)
      }
  }
});
```

Is there a way to send the full email as username?

Answer (score 1):

We can use the the [Auth0 Management API v2](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2) to update the `username` using [`patch_users_by_id`](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Users/patch_users_by_id) (make sure to include the `connection` name when sending a patch to update the username).

To elaborate, I believe it depends on the type of connection you have that will determine how the username gets set. Example, for [database connections](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/database/require-username) if `Requires Username` is enabled then users can set the option for username so that they can then login with either their username or email address. If you're using the database connection you might also want to check the [username length](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/database/require-username#username-length) in the [Dashboard > Connections > Database](https://manage.auth0.com/#/connections/database) > `your-db-connection` >  **Username length**. What type of connection do you use? What's your use case that you want to set  `username` to the `email`? 
Depending on what you're trying to achieve we can look into using a [Rule](https://auth0.com/docs/rules/current) to store data in the `user_metadata`.